# How do I build nginx debian packages from source?

Tags: nginx, build, debian

I am trying to build [nginx stable repository](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx) by adding some modules that are not included in the official distributions but I discovered that the the makefile does not have any step for creating the .deb files.

So while the build works, building the debs seems to be missing from the source code.

Comment: Why not build from debian source? `apt-get source nginx`, patch, debuild

Comment: There is a debian utility to create a deb out of any compiled source: `checkinstall`

Comment: If you want easily create a deb from binaries I recommend you to check  [this tutorial](https://www.rsm.website/tutorials/gnu-linux/debian-packages#build) and [this software](https://www.rsm.website/software/gnu-linux/software/build-deb) you wont find more shorter & easy!